# MySQL UPDATE error column doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update one table with the contents on another where player_id in one table matches id in another.

My query is:

```
UPDATE match_request
SET first_name = users.first_name, last_name = users.last_name, phone = users.phone, email = users.phone
WHERE player_id = users.id
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out why this doesn't work. The error is that users.id is an unknown column but it is definitely there and all lower case.

Comment: Please read about merge statement. Where have you defined users table in the query?

Comment: I don't see any table called `users` in your query.  Where is `users.first_name` from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with the `users` table.

```
UPDATE match_request AS m
JOIN users AS u ON m.player_id = u.id
SET m.first_name = u.first_name, m.last_name = u.last_name, m.phone = u.phone, m.email = u.phone
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! A steep leaning curve for me I'm developing a web app from complete scratch and there are gaps in my knowledge! I'll accept this answer once I'm allowed to in 10 minutes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE match_request
INNER JOIN users ON match_request.player_id = users.id
SET match_request.first_name = users.first_name,
    match_request..last_name = users.last_name,
    match_request..phone = users.phone,
    match_request..email = users.phone
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this kind of sql queries needs scalar value, character, string or joined table values, such an example given as

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column_name1 = 'XXXX', column_name2 = 5 
WHERE column_named_id = 3;
```

but here you use where clause with another tables column name  `users.id`.

You must first join the tables and then use where clause as whatevet users table is ;

```
UPDATE match_request AS t1
INNER JOIN users ON t1.primary_key_id = users.foreign_key_id
SET t1.first_name = users.first_name, t1.last_name = users.last_name, t1.phone = users.phone, t1.email = users.phone
WHERE  t1.player_id = users.id
```

Here you must fill only `inner join` statement